# Steps to view SAR imagery (SICD) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sar

I would like to view SAR imagery in a SICD file in QGIS.  I am able to load the file and view it as a singleband gray image, but the image does not look correct - features are not detectable and the image looks grainy.  I've worked with the min/max adjustments, but that hasn't helped.  I've seen posts of others using SAR imagery that look great and the text simply says to load the image and then details are given for further processing.  Could someone please provide the necessary steps to load SICD images in QGIS?

Comment: It might help if you post an image example of how it comes out to see the problem.
Also has it been pre-processed, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a perfect solution, the Raster Calculator functionality in QGIS can be helpful here.  Typical SICD's are stored as in-phase and quadrature (I & Q) representations of complex values (although magnitude and phase is supported...but rarely found).

For a publicly available example SICD from the NGA Sensor Independent XML (SIX) library, the following raster calculator entry was found to produce a magnitude channel from I&Q bands:

```
log10 (  sqrt ( 
"sicd_example_1_PFA_RE32F_IM32F_VV@1" * 
"sicd_example_1_PFA_RE32F_IM32F_VV@1" + 
"sicd_example_1_PFA_RE32F_IM32F_VV@2" * 
"sicd_example_1_PFA_RE32F_IM32F_VV@2" 
)  )
```

While not technically correct, I added log10 at the beginning because I did not immediately find a non-linear remap within QGIS.  For the dynamic range and distribution of intensities in SAR, this is typically required. Within the layer properties, I found that reducing gamma (under Color Rendering in the Symbology tab) and setting 'Blending mode' to 'Darken' also improved visualization.

In-depth details on SAR magnitude and phase encoding and the conversion between I&Q and magnitude and phase values:  https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1340052

Example SICD files: https://github.com/ngageoint/six-library/wiki/Sample-SICDs

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!  The instructions were very clear and easy to follow.